# Flask: ImportError: No module named folder.file

Tags: python, linux, flask, deployment, server

I have a flask app based on [Atlantis Dashboard](https://github.com/app-generator/flask-dashboard-atlantis).

It runs just fine on Windows using the command:

- `flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000`.

Now I'm trying to deploy it on Linux server, I cloned the project and tried to start it:

- `flask run`
- `py -m app.app`
- `waitress-serve --port=8001 run:app`
- Tried to change import syntax
- .. another 20x trials

**But can't make it work! I keep getting the error:**

```
* Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/www/project_x/app/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    app.config.from_object('app.configuration.Config')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/config.py", line 174, in from_object
    obj = import_string(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 585, in import_string
    ImportStringError, ImportStringError(import_name, e), sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 576, in import_string
    module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [obj_name])
  File "/var/www/project_x/app/configuration.py", line 8, in <module>
    from secret.keys import SECRET
ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'app.configuration.Config'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'app' found in '/var/www/project_x/app/__init__.pyc'.
- 'app.configuration' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named secret.keys
```

**Project structure:**

```
project_x
- app
   - __pycache__
   - __init__.py
   - configuration.py
   - api.py
   - static
   - templates
   - secret
        - keys.py
- run.py
```

**What did I do wrong? and why is Linux different??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the main cause, virtual env was not activated.
Using this `. venv/bin/activate` activated the env and fixed the issue